# Mysql - Monthwise Partitioning scanning all partitions instead of one

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I created a table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
id INT NOT NULL,
fname VARCHAR(30),
lname VARCHAR(30),
hired datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '2000-01-01')
PARTITION BY RANGE ( Month(hired) ) (
PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (2),
PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (3),
PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (4),
PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN (5),
PARTITION p5 VALUES LESS THAN (6),
PARTITION p6 VALUES LESS THAN (7),
PARTITION p7 VALUES LESS THAN (8),
PARTITION p8 VALUES LESS THAN (9),
PARTITION p9 VALUES LESS THAN (10),
PARTITION p10 VALUES LESS THAN (11),
PARTITION p11 VALUES LESS THAN (12),
PARTITION p12 VALUES LESS THAN maxvalue
);
```

As you can see above, month wise partitioning has been done.

Next I add a few records to the table.

After inserting records I query the table to verify whether it is fetching data from the intended partitions.

When I give the below query,

```
EXPLAIN PARTITIONS SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM employees 
WHERE hired BETWEEN'2015-01-01' AND '2015-03-01';
```

Ideally it must scan partitions, p1, p2 and p3.
But the explain result shows that it is scanning all the partitions.

I slightly changed the partitioning from month wise to year wise as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE employees partition BY range(Year(hired))
PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (2001),
PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (2005),
PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (2010),
PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN (2015),
PARTITION p5 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE);
```

Now I query as before:

```
EXPLAIN PARTITIONS SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM employees
WHERE hired BETWEEN '2015-01-01' and '2015-03-01';
```

The results show that it is fetching data only from partition p5.

I have no idea why it is working for year wise partitioning and not monthwise. The same issue has been observed for day wise as well.

Please help me know why MySQL is behaving in such a way.

Comment: Please make sure your code is properly formatted. I have done it for you this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have found yet another case where `PARTITIONing` is not useful.

```
BETWEEN '2015-01-01' and '2015-03-01'; -- could have been optimized
BETWEEN '2015-01-01' and '2016-03-01'; -- must touch all partitions
```

The partition pruning code is too dumb to tell the difference between the two.

Even if the pruning were working as expected, the query would be no faster than having a non-partitioned table with `INDEX(hired)`.  Do you have any queries that might work better?

[More rants and tips on `PARTITION`](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint).

Answer (score 1):

MySQL behavior in regards to "monthwise" partitioning vs. "yearwise" partitioning is documented in the MySQL Reference Manual here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-pruning.html

*excerpt*

> ... optimization can be applied whenever the partitioning expression consists of an equality or a range which can be reduced to a set of equalities, or when the partitioning expression represents an increasing or decreasing relationship.
>
> Pruning can also be applied for tables partitioned on a **DATE** or DATETIME column when the partitioning expression uses the **YEAR()** or TO_DAYS() function. In addition, in MySQL 5.7, pruning can be applied for such tables when the partitioning expression uses the TO_SECONDS() function.

---

I think the root of the issue is that the MONTH(datecol) is not an "ascending" relationship. If you specified a range of '2014-11-01' to '2015-02-01', that would be partitions p11, p12,  and then the wrap around to p01, p02.

The range in your query is a special case.

(Note that partitioning by YEAR() and TO_DAYS() *do* represent an ascending relationship. That is, higher values in the column will never wrap back to a lower partition.)

To get partition pruning with your monthwise partitioning, I think you try adding to your query equality predicates on the partition expression. For example:

```
   WHERE MONTH(hiredate) IN (1,2)
     AND hiredate >= '2015-01-01'
     AND hiredate < '2015-03-01'
```

MySQL *might* be able to use that first condition for partition pruning.

Or, performance may just become disastrous, with MySQL evaluating the expression (the MONTH() function) on every flipping row in the table.

---

Irregardless of the partitioning scheme, you want an index defined

```
 ... ON employees(hiredate)
```

With that, even if you don't get any partition pruning, there will be a little bit of overhead to check each partition. But performing the range check won't require a fullscan of every row in the partition. MySQL can use a range scan operation on the index, to efficiently check a partition for a "no rows found here" in a lot of the partitions.

Bottomline, it's the absence of an appropriate index that's killing performance.

Partitioning isn't a silver bullet for performance of queries. Indexes aren't silver bullets either, but appropriate indexes are a lot more precious metallic, shiny, and bullet shaped than partitioning is.